# Handling fatal exceptions in C#?

Tags: c#

How can I execute some code when my program experiences a fatal error and crashes? For example, something goes wrong and the box pops up that say "TestApp.exe has encountered an error and needs to close." and then I want to write to a file with an error code and say a report of the last few things that were entered into the program. How would I do this in C#??

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the type of application you are writing there are different ways. You may take a look at the [following article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exception/UnhandledExceptionClass.aspx) to see how this could be achieved in a WinForms application.

Comment: A top-level exception handler (top of the blog post) that catches Exception -- not a specific type -- is a good idea. In fact, that's one of the very few places where you should catch Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's a bad idea to write handlers for `Exception`, `FatalException` and two more types, you should be more specific in `try.. catch` clause. Try explore the `Application` class, especially its `SetUnhandledExceptionMode`. You can find a nice example on how to use it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157905.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are asking here.

Regular exceptions you can get through try/catch.

However if you are running any external dll that may for example get Corrupted state exceptions (CSEs) you need to enable legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy in your app.config  (but dont forget that there is a reason for Microsoft to remove this as default as it was before. You should try to fix this kind of errors not only catch them and forget them)

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/All-about-Corrupted-State-Exceptions-in-NET4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For logging errors to the file you may use [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

Any way it should look like:

```
try
{
// Something potentially dangerous
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    Logger.Append(Ex.Message);
}
```